Setting 'H' in the Chebyshev approximation
For the Chebyshev approximation, \$ \frac{V_0}{V_{in}} = \frac {h}{D_n(s)} \$, and I was wondering how you actually set \$h\$. I know that \$h\$ is chosen to so that:
\$ \frac{V_0}{V_{in}} = 1 \$ for \$n (odd) \$
\$ \frac{V_0}{V_{in}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^2}}\$ for \$n (even) \$
In example questions, \$h\$ is often set to high precision numbers, but I am not sure where these numbers are derived from. Here is an example to illustrate what I mean:

I understand everything up until the last line, where \$h\$ is chosen to be \$0.389223\$. As \$n\$ is odd, I know that this value of \$h\$ should set \$ \frac{V_0}{V_{in}} = 1 \$, but I don't see how this is the case.
EDIT: I've gathered that by setting \$s = 0\$ in both \$n(odd)\$ and \$n(even)\$ cases, you can derive \$h\$. For the even case, is there a formula for finding \$ \varepsilon \$ if it is not provided in the question?

Here is that final line (with red boxes around two values): -

And, at DC (s=0), the only terms left are: -
$$\dfrac{h}{(0.42011)(0.92649)}$$
Hence, if you want the TF to be unity at DC, \$h\$ must equal \$(0.42011)(0.92649) = 0.389227713\$
